# Spark reduce by

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, reduce

I have streaming data coming as follows

```
id, date, value
i1, 12-01-2016, 10
i2, 12-02-2016, 20
i1, 12-01-2016, 30
i2, 12-05-2016, 40
```

Want to reduce by id to get aggregate value info by date like

output required from rdd is for a given id and list(days 365)
I have to put the value in the list position based on day of year like 12-01-2016 is 336 and as there are two instances for device i1 with same date they should be aggregated

```
id, List [0|1|2|3|...              |336|  337|  |340|  |365]
i1,                                |10+30|        - this goes to 336 position

i2,                                       20     40 -- this goes to 337 and 340 position
```

Please guide the reduce or group by transformation to do this.

Comment: Is this Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming? What have you tried so far? Where's the issue?

Comment: Issue is the List updation on the fly and how to reduce do If I reduce by id all the values will be aggregated irrespective of day of year

Comment: What code do you have already? Is this Spark Streaming?

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to put the result in array finally?

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you the basic code snippet with few assumptions as you haven't specified about the language, data source or data format.

```
JavaDStream<String> lineStream = //Your data source for stream
JavaPairDStream<String, Long> firstReduce = lineStream.mapToPair(line -> {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    String idDate = fields[0] + fields[1];
    Long value = Long.valueOf(fields[2]);
    return new Tuple2<String, Long>(idDate, value);
}).reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> {
    return (v1+v2);
});
firstReduce.map(idDateValueTuple -> {
    String idDate = idDateValueTuple._1();
    Long valueSum = idDateValueTuple._2();
    String id = idDate.split(",")[0];
    String date = idDate.split(",")[];
    //TODO parse date and put the sumValue in array as you wish
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I am using scala

Comment: Doesn't matter. Same above code can be easily converted to scala

Comment: i dont think the above logic will work for the case with id=id2 as the date is different for each entry for id2 in the given sample data.

Comment: It will work because I am reducing on a string of form <id,date>. In case of id=i2, My stream will be: [<"i2,12-02-2016", 20> <"i2,12-05-2016", 40>] after reduce

Comment: exactly!! i think the reduce should only be on the id column and the date column plays its role only deciding the position of the value in the List. i might have understood the problem altogether in a wrong way. also please go through my solution it may make my point clear.

Comment: I have gone through your code(note: I am a beginner in scala). From my understanding, my approach is bottom up, where as yours looks top down. My code, first sums up all the values for a particular day of an id and then aggregates the values of all the days for that id. Where as your code, prepares <id,array with value> first and then aggregates the result.

Answer (score 0):

Can only reach this far. Am not sure how to add each element of an array in the final step. Hope this helps!!!If you get the last step or any alternate way,appreciate if you post it here!!

```
def getDateDifference(dateStr:String):Int = {
val startDate = "01-01-2016" 
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")
val oldDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter)
val currentDate = dateStr
val newDate = LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter)
return newDate.toEpochDay().toInt - oldDate.toEpochDay().toInt
}
def getArray(numberofDays:Int,data:Int):Iterable[Int] = {
val daysArray = new Array[Int](366)
daysArray(numberofDays) = data
return daysArray
}
val idRDD = <read from stream>
val idRDDMap = idRDD.map { rec => ((rec.split(",")(0),rec.split(",")(1)),
        (getDateDifference(rec.split(",")(1)),rec.split(",")(2).toInt))}
val idRDDconsiceMap = idRDDMap.map { rec => (rec._1._1,getArray(rec._2._1, rec._2._2)) }
val finalRDD = idRDDconsiceMap.reduceByKey((acc,value)=>(???add each element of the arrays????))
```